# How to use aws lambda to proxy request

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, web-crawler

I want to use lambda to proxy request, so that I can have many different IP addresses to access some websites (for my web-crawler). Is it possible? If so, how to do it. Waiting for your advice. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add more detail please? It's not clear what you want to do and what part you are stuck on.

Comment: @mattfreake I'm  really really  sorry for my poor English. I had though my question had been expressed clearly, but it was not. I want to make aws lambda as my proxy server(something like that), so that i can use it to crawl web page through different ip.Sorry aggin

Comment: No worries. The best thing to do is try some stuff (set up an AWS lambda that just prints "hello world", change it to just hit one single web-site, etc) and when you hit a specific, technical problem, ask a question. Open-ended questions like "Is it possible?" tend to get closed.